# mySQL - performance of UNION statements

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, dynamic-queries

I need to combine two tables with identical columns and use the result in complex JOIN queries, but it degrades the performance a lot. This query with UNIONs has an execution time of 7 sec:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `admin`.`Fund_ID`,
                `admin`.`Fund_Name`
FROM (
        (SELECT *
         FROM `admin`)
      UNION
        (SELECT *
         FROM `admin_custom`
         WHERE `user_id`=361)) admin
LEFT JOIN (
             (SELECT *
              FROM `quant1`)
           UNION
             (SELECT *
              FROM `quant1_cust`
              WHERE `user_id`=361)) quant1 
ON (quant1.`Fund ID`=`admin`.`Fund_ID`)
WHERE quant1.`VaR 95`>-0.028
```

But replacing a UNION clause by a simple table makes it only 0.006 sec. How can I fix the performance issues?

Comment: Are you sure you **HAVE** to use UNION? Could there be duplicates (as the difference between UNION and UNION ALL is to remove duplicates), if not, you can use UNION ALL

Comment: Indexing is almost certainly the answer. Use `EXPLAIN` on your query to find out what MySQL is doing, then look at indexing the slowest parts.

Comment: No need for the `outer join` since you're including that result in your `where` criteria...

Comment: The are no duplicates, all records are different. What happens with indexes when we use UNION? Does it re-build all indexes of the combined table (a result of UNION)? Or the result is not indexed at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could do an 'additive change' to the database, to create commonality between the UNIONED tables. This would be a refactoring that *only adds tables & columns*, preserving read compatability with unchanged application code.

In this example, you'd create a common table "to the left of" `admin` and `admin_custom` which would then be joined from it. This would have the Fund ID, a TYPE (so you knew which you were joining to) and, if possible, other useful common columns.

You would also create a common table "to the left of" `quant1` and `quant1_cust` which would then be join from *that*.

You would then change the query to use the Fund-ID linkage from the common tables, replacing your UNION clauses with either just the "Common Table" (if possible) or `"Common Table" left outer join Legacy1 left outer join Legacy2`.

I don't understand "what" these tables really are, so I can't help you with sensible naming. (Naming is the most important part of design, and you should have explained this in your question.)

But this approach did work very well for a major Government project I led, where the common tables were DOCUMENT and DOC_ELEMENT. Tree-structured documents with 8 different document types and no pre-existing commonality.

In our case, DOCUMENT was added "to the left of" RFP, TENDER, PRICEPLAN etc and provided the commonality.

It's not total backwards compatability -- you will need to change the INSERT code, of the application. And if you're getting into refactoring, you might want to consider *putting the same table structure into the same table*.

Best thing would be to trial the possible structures out, verify possible performance, and map out what code changes would be required. You can then pick a trajectory.

Comment: I cannot JOIN these table on "Find ID", because there are no common Fund IDs: these tables have an identical structure and no common key values. Think about these UNIONED tables as a single table cut in half.

Comment: That's how I understood it, actually. "Joining on Fund_ID" refers to the overall `LEFT JOIN` of your query, which -- as posted -- says it's on Fund ID. _I could probably explain a lot more clearly, if your question identified actually what the UNIONed tables logically are (on both the left side, and the right) and told us their PKs. As it is, due to lack of detail from you I've not been able to be precise & you've mis-read my answer._  **Read it again, and post the logical meaning of your UNIONed tables & their PKs.**

Answer (score 0):

This involves some guesswork - does `admin` relate just to `quant1`? and `admin_custom` to just `quant1_cust`? Then this should reduce the effort required for a distinct list of those 2 fields:

```
SELECT `Fund_ID`, `Fund_Name`
FROM `admin`
INNER JOIN `quant1` ON `admin`.`Fund_ID` = `quant1`.`Fund_ID`
                   AND `quant1`.`VaR 95`>-0.028

UNION

SELECT `Fund_ID`, `Fund_Name`
FROM `admin_custom`
INNER JOIN `quant1_cust` ON `admin_custom`.`Fund_ID` = `quant1_cust`.`Fund_ID`
                        AND `admin_custom`.`user_id` = `quant1_cust`.`user_id`
                        AND `quant1_cust`.`VaR 95`>-0.028
WHERE `admin_custom`.`user_id`=361
;
```

Looking at your existing query structure there are several things I would suggest you do not do. There is no point in using UNION and SELECT DISTINCT. Don't use select * with UNION or UNION ALL - be specific and only involve the fields you really need. And your existing where clause does suppress any nulls returned by a left join - so don't use left join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT --<< effort for distinctiveness here
...
FROM (
      SELECT * --<< too many fields
      ...
      UNION --<< effort for distinctiveness here

      SELECT * --<< too many fields
      ...
     )
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT * --<< too many fields
            ...
            UNION --<< effort for distinctiveness here

            SELECT * --<< too many fields
            ...
           ) quant1
WHERE quant1 ...
```

edit: an alternate - sorry, it might be easier to follow this way:

```
SELECT `Fund_ID`, `Fund_Name`
FROM `admin`
INNER JOIN `quant1` ON `admin`.`Fund_ID` = `quant1`.`Fund_ID`
WHERE `quant1`.`VaR 95`>-0.028

UNION

SELECT `Fund_ID`, `Fund_Name`
FROM `admin_custom`
INNER JOIN `quant1_cust` ON `admin_custom`.`Fund_ID` = `quant1_cust`.`Fund_ID`
                        AND `admin_custom`.`user_id` = `quant1_cust`.`user_id`
WHERE `admin_custom`.`user_id`=361
AND `quant1_cust`.`VaR 95`>-0.028
;
```

Comment: I've playing with different options for a day or so and it looks as UNION is a very bad way to go. The example of the code is just a fragment of a dynamically built WHERE clause, while it may contain 15-20 fields. That's why I need * for UNION. I think that the problem is with UNIONing large tables: the UNIONed table is not indexed - that's why further SELECT queries are very slow.

The best solution I've found so far is to INSERT SELECT the content of the 2nd table and work with a single table for all joins. Much faster, but I will need to sync these tables.